# A checksum mismatch error connecting to Segway RMP400

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Well,I have an error when I connect the segway rmp400 to my laptop (installed the Hydro on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS)via two USB interfaces and run the **segway_rmp package**.This is the error information:

```
birl@birl-Hasee:~$ rosrun segway_rmp segway_rmp_node


[ INFO] [1416217225.551290667]: Accel limits: linear: pos = 0.000000, neg = 0.000000, angular: pos = 0.000000, neg = 0.000000.
[ INFO] [1416217225.555137737]: Velocity limits: linear: 0.000000, angular: 0.000000.  
[ INFO] [1416217225.561383781]: Connecting to Segway RMP via serial on serial port: /dev/ttyUSB0  
[ INFO] [1416217225.586345266]: Segway RMP Ready.
[ERROR] [1416217225.587296505]: Checksum mismatch...
```

Now,I just have no ideas about this.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/197639/a-checksum-mismatch-error-connecting-to-segway-rmp400/) by [BIRLxu](https://answers.ros.org/users/20843/birlxu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-11-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sorry, I don't really know why this would happen either, but there are two major possibilities.

The first is that the Segway you are using it with does not have the same communication protocol. At some point all the new Segway models started using a new protocol which does not work with my `libsegwayrmp` library. I thought the rmp400 should work (it is basically two rmp200's strapped together). But if you are using the rmp440x or some other more modern version then it may just not work.

The other reason for getting a checksum error would be that you are getting data corruption. I've seen this before when I had some grounding problems on my rmp setup in college, but it usually resulted in the usb device disconnecting rather than just checksum errors.

You should also try USB vs Serial mode and see if that makes a difference.

One last thought is that you are having two instances of the `libsegwayrmp` driver connect to the same device, which might "work" in that both can open and interact with the device, but then may cause the data stream to be corrupted. I'm pretty dubious of this scenario, but it was just a thought.

Hope this helps some.

**EDIT:**

Here is the example program which demonstrates how to connect with different options: https://github.com/segwayrmp/libsegwayrmp/blob/master/examples/segwayrmp_example.cc

Also, I don't think it documented, but the `segway_rmp` node should take ROS parameters for all the different connection types:

https://github.com/segwayrmp/segway_rmp/blob/master/src/segway_rmp_node.cpp#L429-459

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2014-11-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BIRLxu](https://answers.ros.org/users/20843/birlxu/) on 2014-11-20**:
Thank you!Yes,your driver shold also work on rmp400,after all,it is applicable to the mp200.I tried to connect my pc to the rmp400 using just one USB and it was right! The error just occurs when I use two USB. I have a guess that the driver is just suitable for one rmp200( just like its windows demo

**Comment by [BIRLxu](https://answers.ros.org/users/20843/birlxu/) on 2014-11-20**:
I have amended the demo to access two USB interfaces and it has good worked on rmp400.Did you have tried to drive a rmp400 using the `segway_rmp` package? And what's the relationship of the `segway_rmp` packege and the `libsegway` library?

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2014-11-20**:
You should be able to run `segway_rmp` twice, each in a namespace (like front and back), and each with a different device option. If you are using serial a different serial port, or if you are using USB then by serial number or by device index. I'll add a like to an example in my answer.